# Getting a variable from ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, viewcontroller

We are making an app that, right now, reads a QR code, and draws a square over it on the phone screen. It will later be an Augmented Reality app.

My partner and I are fairly new to Swift and are wondering how we can get a value that resides within the `ViewController` file(Ex. `var value = ""`) and call it in another class called `barcodeClass`.

So we are trying to get "value" from `ViewController` by calling a func `getValue` in `barcodeClass`. Not even sure if this is how Swift works, so any help would be great. If this isn't clear, I can try to clarify.

Comment: Make variable to public or make method as public

Comment: Can you not just access the variable? By default all methods and properties are public.

Comment: Sounds like you're architecting this wrong from the start. Can you give more information? What is `BarcodeClass` and what is supposed to do?

Comment: @ABakerSmith they are not `public` by default, but they are visible to everything within the module where they are defined.

Comment: My bad, that is indeed correct. They have internal access by default.

Answer (score 0):

The `barcodeClass` needs a pointer to the instance of `ViewController` that you have. Once you have that, you can access its properties, or call its methods (unless you've made those private).

How you get that pointer depends on your app structure. If `ViewController` creates the instance of `barcodeClass`, then it would be better to use a delegate protocol, and `ViewController` can set itself as the delegate when it creates the barcode instance. None of this is specific to Swift, you would do the same in Objective-C.

Answer (score -1):

Let me show you an example.

1. Make a structure like this
2. add a static var

`struct (Whatever you want to call it, I will call it structure) {
static var (Name, I will call it awesome) = (Value)
}`

3. From a different file access it my writing the structure name then the variable.

`structure.awesome`

4. Done

Comment: Make sure this is declared outside of your classes.